# Merging (or union) two result set with MySQL

Tags: mysql, merge, sum, union

I have two seperate MySQL queries which return two set of results that look like this

**Query 1 result**:

```
country  | buyers | payment |  num_of_sales
UK       |   5    | 106.45  |    4
Thailand |   6    | 250.10  |    3
```

and:

**Query 2 result**:

```
country | buyers | payment |  num_of_sales
UK      |   2    | 150.00  |    1
Norway  |   9    | 310.80  |    2
```

All I need is to merge / union them so the final result will look like this:

**Expected result**

```
 country | buyers | payment |  num_of_sales
 UK      |   7    | 256.45  |    5
Thailand |   6    | 250.10  |    3
 Norway  |   9    | 310.80  |    2
```

Please help, and if possible, with a bit of explaination. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the two initial queries please?

Comment: Thank you, I manage to twist it around and get expected result similar to the way Mahmoud Gamal did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to merge the two queries results' sets into one result set, then use `GROUP BY country` with `SUM` to get the totals you are looking for, something like this:

```
SELECT
  country, 
  SUM(buyers) AS buyers, 
  SUM(payment) AS payment, 
  SUM(num_of_sales) AS num_of_sales
FROM
(  
   SELECT country, buyers, payment, num_of_sales
   FROM -- your query1 results
   UNION ALL
   SELECT country, buyers, payment, num_of_sales
   FROM -- your  query2 result2  
) AS t
GROUP BY country
```